# How to allow outbound requests from a Google Cloud Run to external MySql instance

Tags: google-cloud-run

I've created a google cloud run service, acting as an api which needs to connect to a mysql instance correctly hosted in aws rds.  I can see that the google cloud run container is unable to connect to the mysql server instance.

My suspicion is that outbound connections are blocked from the google cloud run container.

Hence my question is if anyone knows how to allow/configure outbound requests in gcloud.

I can run the container locally and connect to AWS RDS successfully. On Cloud Run I get this error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Comment: What’s the error? Cloud Run can connect to the outside world out of the box, without any extra configuration. Can you connect to it from your laptop by running the container locally?

Comment: What are your security group settings for RDS in AWS? Note that Cloud Run does not publish public IP addresses for you to use in AWS Security Groups. This means that you have to open RDS to the world which I do not recommend. Your problem is most likely your security settings in AWS and not with Cloud Run.

Comment: Hi @AhmetB-Google, yep have docker pull the image from the gcloud docker registry (gcr.io) and can confirm the connectionstring is pointing at the AWS RDS mysql instance, and successfully retrieves data.  The error that I am see in the Google Cloud Run logs in the container is:

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Comment: Given that connectivity isn't an issue from my laptop, I wouldn't think there were any security settings astray on AWS's end (I haven't modified anything from the default security group settings).  Unless, there is something particular about gcloud -> AWS.  Appreciate the help on this one guys.

Comment: Thanks, I'm asking internally why could this be happening.

Comment: @lancearmstruong are you calling to MySQL while Cloud Run app is processing a request? Timeouts might happen if you do things on Cloud Run apps while it's not handling requests (and hence CPU is throttled nearly to zero).

Comment: @AhmetB-Google I have timeout issue on fully managed cloud run on a Golang app where I receive a request and handout the work to a worker (done with goroutines). So this CPU throttling means I can not use Cloud Run for this sort of use cases right?

Comment: I am having a similar issue, check this page (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#sandbox), in my case I found out that it is a gVisor sandbox limitation, following instructions from that link above I found these debug messages: Container Sandbox: Unsupported syscall setsockopt(0x13,0x0,0xb,0x3ef3565fdf64,0x4,0x13). It is very likely that you can safely ignore this message and that this is not the cause of any error you might be troubleshooting. Please, refer to https://gvisor.dev/c/linux/amd64/setsockopt for more information."